# Regarding analyticity and point outside the simple closed curve

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

The problem is to evaluate
$$
\oint \frac{d z}{z-a}
$$
where $C$ is any simple closed curve and $z=a$ is a point outside $C$.

The solution to this problem says that because $z=a$ is a point outside $C$, the function $ \frac{ 1}{z-a}$ is analytic everywhere inside and on $C$, the integral above is zero (via Cauchy's Theorem)

My question is why does the fact  $z=a$ being outside $C$ imply the analyticity of $ \frac{ 1}{z-a}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't. For each $a\in\Bbb C$, the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\Bbb C\setminus\{a\}&\longrightarrow&\Bbb C\\&z&\mapsto&\dfrac1{z-a}\end{array}\tag1$$is an analytic map. It turns out that, when $a$ is outside $C$ (to be more correct: when $a$ is outside the region of $\Bbb C$ bounded by $C$), then the domain of the analytic map $f$ contains the region of $C$ bounded by $C$ and, when that happens, $\int_Cf=0$ (for *every* analytic map, by the way, no just for those of the form $(1)$).

Comment: Okay, so basically the point $a$ is a singular point, but as we are evaluating the integral over the curve C and $a$ belongs outside this curve, it won't affect the analyticity of the function, that is, the function will never "get" to be not analytic as the singular point is outside C, and therefore it will be analytic and using Cauchy's theorem, we get the closed integral to be zero.
Is this reasoning correct? I just have a small doubt on how do we know that it is an analytic map?

Comment: No, it is not correct. The map $f$ **is** analytic (since it is the quotient of two analytic maps). *Nothing* can affect that. What happens is that, according to Cauchy's theorem, if $C$ is a closed path such that the region $R$ of $\Bbb C$ enclosed by $C$ is part of the domain of $f$ (that's the case here, when $a\notin R$), then $\int_Cf=0$.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you dumb it down a shade for me? I'm not a mathematics student but a physics student learning complex analysis for the first time.

Comment: I would love to help you, but I don't know what is it that you don't understand.

Comment: These are my doubts:
1) $ \frac{ 1}{z-a}$ has a singular point at $z=a$. Can I say that $ \frac{ 1}{z-a}$ is analytic everywhere except at $z=a$. If not, why?

2) If it were analytic everywhere except at $z=a$ then choosing a curve such that $z=a$  is outside that region would make $ \frac{ 1}{z-a}$ analytic within that curve and therefore, its closed integral around this curve should be zero. Is it reasoning correct?

Comment: 1) Yes, $f$ has a singular point at $a$; in $\Bbb C\setminus\{a\}$, $f$ is analytic. 2) Yes, that is also correct.

Comment: Okay, got it! My first comment was just the second subquestion in my recent comment, but I may have poorly worded it. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.